# Shell version and commands version

Tags: linux, shell

The  man page of `echo` command states:

> your shell may have its own version of echo...

What does it exactly mean and how to check which shell have which echo version?

Answer (score 2):

You can check as follows: the command

```
$ type -a echo
  echo is a shell builtin
  echo is /bin/echo
```

returns **all** possible versions of the command in question (*echo*, in our case); this shows that I have **both** an executable called */bin/echo*, **and** a shell builtin, *i.e.* a different command inside my shell with the same name, and performing nearly exactly the same function.

In order to know which one is executed among these (two) possibilities, try

```
 $ type -t echo
   builtin
```

which shows that you if you just hit *echo something*, the shell builtin will be used, **not** the executable file */bin/echo*. If you insist on using the file, just try

```
$ env echo something
```

In order to get *man* information on either version, you should use

```
$ man echo
```

or

```
$ info echo
```

for the executable file */bin/echo*, and

```
$ help echo
```

for the shell builtin. The comparison of these two outputs will show their differences.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the shells have their own builtin `echo` to speed up the `echo` command. You can check:

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
$ type printf
cp is a tracked alias for /bin/cp
```